# « Ne » et « ni » en fonction des infinitifs et des verbes conjugués

Tags: grammaire, verbes, infinitif, négation, coordination

P. 248 de *Schaum's Outline of French Grammar*, 5<sup>e</sup> édition de Mary Crocker :

> Ni may be used more than twice.
>   Il ne veut ni lire, ni écrire, ni étudier. = 
>   *He wants neither to read, nor to write, nor to study.*

En haut de la p. 292 de [*Principes généraux et particuliers de la langue française*](http://books.google.com/books?id=4AAGAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA292&dq=ni+ne+ne&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=5xvFUt_cD-WWiQe1y4DYCQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=ni%20ne%20ne&f=false) par Noël François de Wailly :

> Voyez les oiseaux du ciel, ils **ne** sèment ni **ne** moissonnent. Considérez les lis des camps, comme ils croissent; il **ne** travaillent ni **ne** filent.

Mes questions :

1. Compte tenu de ce qui précède, faut-il toujours ajouter *ne* avant les verbes conjugués en employant « ne … ni … ni …», mais rien lorsqu'il s'agit d'infinitifs ?
2. Si oui, pourquoi cette différence ?

Answer (score 4):

En gros, *ni* signifie *et* dans une négation. On peut l'utiliser avec des groupes nominaux, des verbes non conjugués (infinitif, participe), des adjectifs, des adverbes, mais pas avec des propositions complètes.

> Je ne l'ai pas vu arriver ni repartir. = Je ne l'ai pas vu arriver, et je ne l'ai pas vu repartir non plus.
>   Je n'ai pas de chat ni de chien. = Je n'ai pas de chat et je n'ai pas de chien.

Lorsque l'on a une énumération dans laquelle tous les éléments sont négatives, il est fréquent d'utiliser *ni* aussi devant le premier élément.

> Je ne l'ai vu ni arriver ni repartir.
>   Je n'ai ni chat ni chien.

Lorsque l'énumération est le sujet de la phrase, c'est la seule solution.

> Ni Pierre ni Paul ne sont venus. = Pierre n'est pas venu et Paul n'est pas venu.

Lorsqu'on a le choix, il y a une légère nuance de sens : si *ni* est répété, on sait dès le début qu'il s'agit d'une énumération, alors que dans le cas contraire on a une phrase déja complète et la clause introduite par *ni* arrive après coup.

Il y a toujours la particule *ne* dans la phrase, comme dans toute phrase négative : *ni* remplace seulement *pas*.

En français moderne, on utilise *ni* que lorsque les deux éléments qui sont liés partagent au moins le verbe ou l'auxiliaire : « il ne sait pas lire ni écrire », « il n'a pas lu ni écrit », mais « il ne lit pas et n'écrit pas ».

En français classique, on pouvait exprimer une négation avec uniquement la particule *ne* ; dans cette langue, on peut utiliser *ni* comme « et … ne » : « il ne lit ni n'écrit ». Cette tournure est désuette même en français très littéraire. On peut aussi tenter « il ne lit pas ni n'écrit », mais là encore je trouve la formulation désuette et je ne l'utiliserais pas de nos jours.

Comment: Je vous suis reconnaissant et ai plussoyé. Pourriez-vous détailler que vous signifiez par `dans cette langue, on peut utiliser ni comme « et … ne »` ? Prière de le faire à l'intérieur de votre réponse SVP.

Answer (score 0):

La réponse la plus simple est qu'on ne met pas *ne* devant un nom, or les infinitifs objets partagent un certain nombre de caractéristiques avec les noms :

> *Il ne veut ni amis ni ennemis.*

Answer (score 0):

En fait, il serait tout à fait possible d'utiliser cette combinaison avec des verbes à l'infinitif. Par exemple:
*Il ne veut ni rester, ni partir* (même si cet exemple n'a pas de sens hors contexte).
Il n'y a pas vraiment de différence.

Ce qu'il faut retenir, c'est que grammaticalement, *ni* fait partie des conjonction de coordination et qu'il s'emploie pratiquement toujours en corrélation avec l'adverbe *ne*.

En revanche, *ne* servant à nier une action, il est forcément placé devant le verbe conjugué (qu'il nie).